# Why are pointers inside of a vector changing when being returned from a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, copy, move-semantics

In my actual application, I'm using a doubly-connected edge list to store subsections of a plane but I've attempted to reduce the code to display my issue.

I have a list containing a custom struct that I need to convert into a vector of pointers to the objects stored in my list. When I do this, inside the function where the conversion happens, the pointers in my vector are the same as the pointers to the objects in the list, but outside of the function (when I've stored the return value inside a variable) the pointers have changed. Why is this occurring? Does it have to do with moving/copying the values? What's going wrong?

Thank you for all your help!

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct* my_other_struct;
}

static std::vector<MyStruct*> structPointers(
    std::list<MyStruct> structs)
{
    std::vector<MyStruct*> struct_pointers;
    struct_pointers.reserve(structs.size());
    std::transform(structs.begin(), structs.end(),
        std::back_inserter(struct_pointers),
        [](MyStruct& ms){ return &ms; });

    for (const MyStruct* ms : struct_pointers)
    {
        // this seems to print out the correct memory address
        std::cout << ms << std::endl;
    }

    return struct_pointers;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<MyStruct> structs;
    structs.push_back(Struct());
    structs.push_back(Struct());
    structs.front().my_other_struct = &structs.back()
    structs.back().my_other_struct = &structs.front()

    std::vector<MyStruct*> struct_pointers = structPointers(structs)

    // I get two different addresses printed out here and I don't understand why
    std::cout << &structs.front() << std::endl;
    std::cout << struct_pointers.front() << std::endl;

    // I get two different addresses printed out here and I don't understand why
    std::cout << &structs.back() << std::endl;
    std::cout << struct_pointers.back() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accept the `structs` by reference, otherwise the pointers that you create inside the function are referring to copies of the original `MyStruct` objects.

```
static std::vector<MyStruct*> structPointers(
    std::list<MyStruct>& structs) // <-- take by reference
```

Here's a [demo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/kZUjMA).

Comment: I've been staring at this for a few days. I hate missing something like that. Thanks! It's making me wait to accept the answer though.

Comment: #@ChristianErmann No problem. Your post has a number of syntax errors (mostly missing semicolons). You should make sure that your program compiles, and produces the behavior you're describing. You'll get better help that way.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the list by value not by reference so you get a new copy of the list when calling the function and this copy is destroyed upon return from the function . what happens is that you copy the list for the function so the copy has separate elements from the original one, and then you append the addresses of the copy's elements to the vector which you return so the addresses belongs to the copy not the original . also the pointers in the vector will be dangling (pointing to destroyed objects)

solution : pass by reference rather than by value :

```
static std::vector<MyStruct*> structPointers(
    std::list<MyStruct>& structs)
```